# Making jQuery event binding play nicely with a locked down, AJAX'd page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am working with a client who has their site hosted via a third party provider. That is to say, the third party (Network Solutions, or NS for short) hosts Ecommerce sites, and provides a web based interface for modifying the site. This obviously has a lot of limitations in terms of customizing the site. The site also uses ASP.NET controls created by NS. Some of these are simple bound controls (e.g. <% ns:Product.Price %> and others are slightly more complicated, such as a Dropdown control which lists the various sizes of a product (e.g. 10lb, 20lb 30lb bags).

The latter control is the one I'm having an issue with. When you select a new product size, the control implements a partial postback somehow via AJAX, loads the new Price, Description, etc., and refreshes the screen. I'm not sure what mechanism is being used for the AJAX, and the source code isn't giving me any hints.

In any event, I have some custom code I need to invoke when the dropdown changes. On document.ready(), I bind the Select element's change() event to call my code (e.g. `$('select').change(){dostuff})`However this only works the first time the Dropdown is changed. When it AJAX updates, the binding is lost.

Basically, what I need is someway to detect that a partial postback has occurred, or even just detect that that a new SELECT control has been rendered, and re-bind the event.

Can this be done. I'm open to alternative ideas as well. I just need it to work.

Comment: Can you post your actual change code? The example you posted has invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

If you're using jQuery < 1.7 - use `delegate` instead:

```
$(document).delegate('select', 'change', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Note how the parameters are switched around...

---

For performance reasons, you should bind the event to the DOM node closest to your select element. For example, if you know that the select element's parent does not change, you'll use this:

```
$('#theSelectsParent').on('change', 'select', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

---

### Further reading:

[jQuery `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
[jQuery `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
[The Difference Between jQuery’s `.bind()`, `.live()`, and `.delegate()`](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/) - Written before `.on()` was introduced, but a good read nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jquery `live()` function.

> Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('select').live("change", function(){
 // do stuff
});
```